# Distribution of Coefficients in Karhunen-Loeve Expansion

Tags: functional-analysis, probability-theory, stochastic-processes

Recall that the [Karhunen-Loeve expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karhunen%E2%80%93Lo%C3%A8ve_theorem) of a second order stochastic process $X(t)$ is an orthogonal series expansion of the form

$$
X(t) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty Z_n \phi_n(t)
$$ where $\phi_n(t)$ are the eigenfunctions of the covariance operator

$$
T_K\phi = \int_a^b K(\cdot,s)\phi(s)ds
$$ Since $K(t,s)$ is positive semi-definite, we know that $\{\phi_n\}$ form an orthonormal basis, so the series converges in the $L^2$ sense for each path $X(t)$.  Furthermore the coefficients $Z_n$ are "orthogonal in probability" i.e. uncorrelated:

$$
E[Z_n] = 0,\quad E[Z_nZ_m] = \lambda_n\delta_{nm}
$$
If the process is Gaussian, then $Z_n$ are independent Gaussians.  What if $X(t)$ is *not* Gaussian?  Is there a **convenient/efficient** way to determine the distribution of $Z_n$?  I realize that I can compute higher moments, form the MGF (if it exists!) and perform inverse Laplace transform, but that seems slightly inconvenient/inefficient (or maybe I'm just lazy).